# Why should software objects have the least scope?

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style, scope

Why is it good to keep the scope of objects "most limited"? I've been advised to do so, and have also read it in Linden's [Expert C Programming](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=OARmhasSZp4C&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=software%20objects%20should%20have%20the%20most%20limited%20scope&source=bl&ots=6KySkr27Bk&sig=6EnQv3Y_lb6wiuNn38Cb6mpJMwQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RHyrUbj_EoLSrQfupYG4Bg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=software%20objects%20should%20have%20the%20most%20limited%20scope&f=false), but couldn't come up with an example where a large scope might be a bad thing.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/148108/1845

Answer (score 2):

If you were to use a global variable for iteration, you would probably only be able to use it in a single function because if that function called another that also used the variable for looping the second use would overwrite the first loop value.

When inspecting the code, the type declaration or initialization will be closer to the code where the object is used making it easier to understand and maintain.

You can reuse the object name in closer segments of the code without conflict.

Smaller scope allows the memory or other resources associated with the object to be reclaimed and reused as soon as possible.